# Is the a formula that can remove a middle initial and middle name only if its there?

Tags: excel-formula

I have tried using this code:

```
=LEFT(G6,FIND(" ",G6))&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(G6," ",REPT(" ",LEN(G6))),LEN(G6)))
```

Whereas G6 contains "Joseph D. Harrison " <-- notice the extra space at the end.

But it only returns the first name of the cell. That the cell contains an extra space at the end of the text string but for the life of me cannot figure out how to remove it in the same line of code. This code line wont remove it, All it get is Joseph.

Comment: Trying to do that is guaranteed to blow up in your face when confronted with someone who has no middle name, but does have a space in their last name.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the cell reference in the SUBSTITUTE with TRIM:

```
=LEFT(G6,FIND(" ",G6))&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(G6)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(G6))),LEN(G6)))
```

[image]

Comment: @GaryDrahos if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.